# How to pass 'equal to' symbol (=) through XML or What is the escape character in XML corresponds to the 'equal to' (=) symbol

Tags: xml, escaping

I would like to pass the below element in the XML. But I am getting error from the target system as it contain '&' and  '=' symbols.

```
<ser:filename>https://example.com:58001/getFileFromexample&path=TEST_ABC</ser:filename>
```

I have replaced the ampersand with & and it works but I couldn't found the escape character for equal to symbol to replace. Please help me to find the same.

Comment: I have replaced the ampersand with &amp; and it works but I couldn't found the escape character for equal to symbol to replace. Please help me to find the same.

Comment: `=` is no special character in XML. But `&` is. So the error must stem from `&`.

Comment: I have removed the '=' symbol and tested with &amp; ,the result is successful. But when '=' is introduced in the XML it fails.